# What does this code do?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
// @flow
import { compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composedStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  __CLIENT__ && window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)(createStore)
```

This code is a file from a React-Redux 'Universal' app boilerplate. I can for most part wrap my head around it, although the falsey case conditional logic in the second argument of the compose function trips me up - what is `f => f` ???

Unless I am mistaken, this is the vanilla JS equivalent of

```
function(f){
  return f;
}
```

In which case, where is the `f` argument coming from, and what does this function *actually* return?? There is no other reference to the `f` variable anywhere else in the file. Very confusing.

Comment: Ha ha ... You nailed it man. That's the JS equivalent in the else condition.

Comment: `f => f` is the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless I am mistaken, this is the vanilla JS equivalent of
>
> ```
> function(f){
>   return f;
> }
> ```

Pretty much, since the function body doesn't use `this` or `arguments`; a couple of notes:

1. The arrow function (`f => f`) closes over `this` and `arguments` (instead of having its own meanings for them), which a `function` expression won't, but given the contents of the function it doesn't matter, as it doesn't use them.
2. Arrow functions *are* vanilla JavaScript (as of ES2015).

> In which case, where is the f argument coming from??

The same place it comes from with any callback you pass into a function: Whatever calls it. This callback is being passed into `compose`, so to know how it's going to be called and with what argument(s), you look at the [`compose`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/compose.html) definition in Redux:

> Each function is expected to accept a single parameter. Its return value will be provided as an argument to the function standing to the left, and so on. The exception is the right-most argument which can accept multiple parameters, as it will provide the signature for the resulting composed function.

So that function will receive whatever the function returned by `applyMiddleware(thunk)` returns.

The only reason for the `f => f` function is so that the author can use a single line; e.g., they needed something for the false operand to the conditional operator. They could have done this instead:

```
let temp = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
if (__CLIENT__ && window.devToolsExtension) {
   temp = window.devToolsExtension()(temp);
}
const composedStore = temp;
```

...but presumably wanted to avoid the temp variable.

Comment: This is the second question in a row of mine you're systematically tearing apart into a great answer. Thanks, I appreciate it :) I think the missing puzzle piece for it to click into place for me is 'The exception is the right-most argument which can accept multiple parameters, as it will provide the signature for the resulting composed function'. Can you provide any insight on what the `signature of the resulting composed function` is?

Comment: @styke: The closest thing to "signatures" that JavaScript functions have is *arity* (the number of declared arguments), which is exposed as the `length` property of the function. So `function foo(a, b){}` has `foo.length` equal to 2; `function bar() { }` has `bar.length` equal to 0. I guess the function returned by `compose` takes its length from the right-most argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just like a *noop*. In case we are not in a Dev Tools extension, the 2nd argument of the compose is a function that only returns the given value.

```
const isDevToolExtension = __CLIENT__ && window.devToolsExtension;
const returnItself = function(f) {
   return f;
}

const composedStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  isDevToolExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : returnItself
)(createStore)
```